# C# Button to Increase/Decrease a Value

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on an inventory system within C# as a small personal project.

I've managed to get the basic functions working within the Form, but I'm having trouble working out how to add a button that will either Increase or decrease the products quantity by 1. The inventory is stored in a ListViewItem object.
Or by having the user enter a value into a textbox, with the product selected and it'll change the quantity of that product without affecting the rest.

The code below shows the code I have written for the user to enter a value manually into a textBox, and clicking the button (with the product selected) will update the quantity. There's no crash, it simply doesn't do anything.

```
    private void PlusOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem list in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            list.SubItems.Add(addBox.Text);
        }
    }

    private void addBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int addOne = int.Parse(addBox.Text);
    }
```

Comment: _list.SubItems.Add(addBox.Text);_ This add a SubItem, nothing to do with adding numbers! If you actually want to add a subitem you need to a) put your ListView in View=Details mode and b) have a Column for each subitem to give it room to display.. - If you instead want to add numbers you need to cast list to int and then add the number, not the text.. Maybe like this: `list.Text = int.Parse(list.Text) + int.Parse(addBox.Text);`

Comment: I have already created to columns one for the Product Name, and the other for the Quantity. I can't seem how to work out how to parse the value correctly.

Comment: Well you are parsing correctly although there are no provisions for testing/validating. TryParse would be used for this. But the parsed value is discarded. Not sure what you actually want . Increase by one or use the textbox value? If the numbers are in the 2nd subitem use `list.SubItems[1].Text = int.Parse(listSubItems[1].Text) + int.Parse(addBox.Text);`

Comment: At this stage, I'm happy with what ever method works. I've tried a few more examples from below and what I've tried previously with a different approach, but keep getting FormatException Errors.

Comment: Why don't you mention the error in the question? You write _There's no crash, it simply doesn't do anything._ Now which? Also do show the text you are trying to parse..

Comment: With the example below, I get an error. With the code I had written, there is no crash, it doesn't do anything at all. With the product selected, and a value entered into the text box and then press the button to make the changes, nothing happens. No values are changed.

Comment: Which line thows? Have you initialized the quantity to 0?

Comment: I have yes. Entered the Products quantity as 0, and tried adding a value, and nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

This will increment all the selected items in your list view.

I'm assuming that you have one ListViewItem per product and the first SubItem stores the quantity value. Subitems are shown from the second column onwards. First column corresponds with the item itself

```
private void PlusOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int quantityColumn = 0;
    int increment = int.Parse(PlusOne.Text);
    foreach (ListViewItem list in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
       int qty = 0;
       if (list.SubItems.Count != 0) {
            qty = int.Parse(list.SubItems[quantityColumn].Text);
        }
        list.SubItems[quantityColumn].Text = (qty + increment).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: _Subitems are shown from the second column onwards._ No : Subitem[0] is Item !!

Comment: @TaW, list is a bad name for the item in the foreach. Really, list is an object of type ListViewItem. A ListViewItem has a property: Subitems, that is a collection of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem. Graphically, ListViewItem.Text is shown at the first column, and subitems in the following columns

Comment: Thank you for that.
I have tried it, but it throws up an FormatException Error.

Comment: No need to explain ListView to me. My comment stands, but we can make it: Subitem[0].Text == Item.Text;  but you are right about op using a bad name.

Comment: Are you sure that the subitem have a valid number. This is an example. You should check if plusOne and the subitem have valid numbers. I have added a check it item has not subitems

Comment: Still the same issue occuring, FormatException error.